# Use identical() ignoring order of items in list

Tags: r

I am playing with indentical function and I have found out that this comparison will return false:

```
identical(list(z = c(1,1,1), q = c(0,0,0)), list(q = c(0,0,0), z = c(1,1,1)))
```

Is there a way to make sure that the order of q and z does not matter, so the answer will be True?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if you have

```
a <- list(z = c(1,1,1), q = c(0,0,0))
b <- list(q = c(0,0,0), z = c(1,1,1))
identical(a,b)
# [1] FALSE
```

they are not identical because

```
a[[1]]
# [1] 1 1 1
b[[1]]
# [1] 0 0 0
identical(a[[1]], b[[1]])
# [1] FALSE
```

which means that the list will behave differently in certain situations.

If you want to compare regardless of order, you can sort the lists by name

```
identical(a[order(names(a))], b[order(names(b))])
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: A trickier, but less symmetric option: `identical(a,b[names(a)])`.

Comment: @Frank That would say that `a <- list(z = c(1,1,1), q = c(0,0,0)); b <- list(q = c(0,0,0), z = c(1,1,1),x=c(3,3,3))` are identical, not sure that's desired.

Comment: Oh, good point. This variant should work, but isn't exactly elegant: `u<-union(names(a),names(b)); identical(a[u],b[u])`...though that would still go amiss if there were repetition of names. I guess there's not as a simple way to use name access to test this as I thought.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for all vectors: ```is_set_same1 <- function(a, b) {
  u <- union(names(a), names(b))
  identical(a[u], b[u])
}; a <- 1:10; b <- 10:20; is_set_same1(a, b)``` gives the wrong answer